# Sublime Text 3 build 3103

Tags: sublime-text-3

I have just installed an upgrade to this build and everything seems OK except the shortcut to 'Quick switch project' which is ctrl+alt+P

I have noticed a boot error 'Unable to open /C/Users/mike/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Default/Default (Windows).sublime-keymap
' which I suspect may be the problem. I have looked at the folder structure and there appears not to be a 'Default' folder within the Packages folder. The relevant file is there but in the User folder.

Anyone suggest what is going on and how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 'Quick switch project' you can use the keybind: `{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+p"], "command": "prompt_select_workspace" }`.